# How to capture from whitespace +{n} to next {n} in regex

Tags: python, regex

I've cleaned up a document to allow me to properly rip it verse by verse. Being weak in regex I cannot seem to find the right expression to extract these verses.

This is the expression I am using:

```
(\t?\t?{\d+}.*){
```

And I'm doing this in python, though I expect that does not matter.

How should I change this to make it simply highlight verses `{x} some verse {x} next verse`, but stopping short just of the next brace?

As you can see, I'm trying to keep it tabs-aware because this doc gives some attention to verse-style writing.

And here is an example doc:

```
{1} The words of the blessing of Enoch, wherewith he blessed the elect [[[[and]]]] righteous, who will be living in the day of tribulation, when all the wicked [[[[and godless]]]] are to be removed. {2} And he took up his parable and said--Enoch a righteous man, whose eyes were opened by God, saw the vision of the Holy One in the heavens, [[which]] the angels showed me, and from them I heard everything, and from them I understood as I saw, but not for this generation, but for a remote one which is for to come. {3} Concerning the elect I said, and took up my parable concerning them:

        The Holy Great One will come forth from His dwelling,
        {4} And the eternal God will tread upon the earth, (even) on Mount Sinai,
        [[And appear from His camp]]
        And appear in the strength of His might from the heaven of heavens.

        {5} And all shall be smitten with fear
        And the Watchers shall quake,
        And great fear and trembling shall seize them unto the ends of the earth.

        {6} And the high mountains shall be shaken,
        And the high hills shall be made low,
        And shall melt like wax before the flame 

        {7} And the earth shall be [[wholly]] rent in sunder,
        And all that is upon the earth shall perish,
        And there shall be a judgement upon all (men).

        {8} But with the righteous He will make peace.

        And will protect the elect,
        And mercy shall be upon them.

        And they shall all belong to God,
        And they shall be prospered,
        And they shall [[all]] be blessed.

        [[And He will help them all]],
        And light shall appear unto them,
        [[And He will make peace with them]].

        {9} And behold! He cometh with ten thousands of [[His]] holy ones
        To execute judgement upon all,
        And to destroy [[all]] the ungodly:

        And to convict all flesh
        Of all the works [[of their ungodliness]] which they have ungodly committed,
        And of all the hard things which ungodly sinners [[have spoken]] against Him.

[BREAK]
[CHAPTER 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply split the text on the verse markers with `re.split`:

```
import re
text = '''{1} The words of the blessing of Enoch, wherewith he blessed the elect [[[[and]]]] righteous, who will be living in the day of tribulation, when all the wicked [[[[and godless]]]] are to be removed. {2} And he took up his parable and said--Enoch a righteous man, whose eyes were opened by God, saw the vision of the Holy One in the heavens, [[which]] the angels showed me, and from them I heard everything, and from them I understood as I saw, but not for this generation, but for a remote one which is for to come. {3} Concerning the elect I said, and took up my parable concerning them:

        The Holy Great One will come forth from His dwelling,
        {4} And the eternal God will tread upon the earth, (even) on Mount Sinai,
        [[And appear from His camp]]
        And appear in the strength of His might from the heaven of heavens.'''

result = [i for i in re.split(r'\{\d+\}', text) if i]
```

`result` has four elements, corresponding to `{1}` through `{4}` above.

Comment: That might be a better solution. I might switch to that.

Answer (score 1):

```
(\t?\t?{\d+}.*?)(?={)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/OCpDb7/1

Edit:

If you want to capture last verse as well,use

```
(\t?\t?{\d+}.*?)(?={|\[BREAK\])
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/OCpDb7/2

Your original regex suffered from `2` problems.

```
(\t?\t?{\d+}.*){
             ^ ^
```

1)You had used `greedy` operator.Use `non greedy` `.*?`

2)You were capturing `{` which would not allow that verse to match as it has been already captured.Use `lookahead` to just assert and not capture.

Comment: Doing a compare of both documents, the document produced has more words than the document used. With mine it is equal. But that could still be an issue I am causing, so I will get back on that.

Comment: @Pipsqweek the correct expression i guess should be https://regex101.com/r/OCpDb7/2 .as the last verse does not have `{` ahead of it, so it should stop when it sees `[BREAK]`

Comment: @Pipsqweek you should accept one of the answers before asking a new one.....if none worked then you should let the ppl know....so that this question gets closed

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is good, but the verses are not always incremented properly in this book (ie, it can jump from verse 5 to 7 due to manuscript details) so I had to retain the verses to "pluck the number" them later. Basically, entire verses along with the number had to be extracted.

The recipe seemed to be this:

```
verse = re.compile(r'([\t+]?{\d+}[^{]*)', re.DOTALL)
```

In context:

```
import re

f = open('thebook.txt', 'r').read()

chapters = f.split('[BREAK]')

verse = re.compile(r'([\t+]?{\d+}[^{]*)', re.DOTALL)

verses = re.findall(verse, chapters[1])
```

Please note, it seems to work properly, but I have to check the results to make sure it accounts for everything.

Comment: This will cause the last verse to capture all the document if there is not `{` at the end