# stop short of multiple strings and characters using '^'

Tags: regex

I'm doing a regex operation that to stop short of either character sets `{` or `\t\t{`.

the first is ok, but the second cannot be achieved using the ^ symbol the way I have been.

My current regex is `[\t+]?{\d+}[^\{]*`

As you can see, I've used `^` effectively with a single character, but I cannot apply it to a string of characters like `\t\t\{`

How can the current regex be applied to consider both of these possibilities?

Example text:

```
{1} The words of the blessing of Enoch, wherewith he blessed the elect and righteous, who will be living in the day of tribulation, when all the wicked and godless are to be removed. {2} And he took up his parable and said--Enoch a righteous man, whose eyes were opened by God, saw the vision of the Holy One in the heavens, which the angels showed me, and from them I heard everything, and from them I understood as I saw, but not for this generation, but for a remote one which is for to come. {3} Concerning the elect I said, and took up my parable concerning them:

        The Holy Great One will come forth from His dwelling,
        {4} And the eternal God will tread upon the earth, [even] on Mount Sinai,
        And appear from His camp
        And appear in the strength of His might from the heaven of heavens.

        {5} And all shall be smitten with fear
        And the Watchers shall quake,
        And great fear and trembling shall seize them unto the ends of the earth.

        {6} And the high mountains shall be shaken,
        And the high hills shall be made low,
        And shall melt like wax before the flame
```

When I do this as a multi-line extract, the indendantation does not maintain for the first line of each block. Ideally the extract should stop short of the \t\t{ allowing it to be picked up properly in the next extract, creating perfectly indented blocks. The reason for this is when they are taken from the database, the \t\t should be detected at the first line to allow dynamic formatting.

Comment: What are you trying to extract?  Also, out of curiosity, is this text take from the book of Enoch?

Comment: I'm trying to extract indented verses precisely, but also get the paragraph-verses correctly as well. And yes this is the Book of Enoch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[\t+]?{\d+}[\s\S]*?(?=\s*{|$)
```

You can use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nNUHJ8/1

Comment: Its definitely working in the demo. Let me plug it into python to see how it goes.

Comment: @Pipsqweek just use `re.findall` without any `flag`

Comment: This works quite well. It seems to remove a tab (so the first line is 1 tab instead of two) but I can work with this and adjust it accordingly. Thank you for your help on that.

Comment: @Pipsqweek do close the other question of urs as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41455359/how-to-capture-from-whitespace-n-to-next-n-in-regex

Comment: I had tried that before but it won't let me delete. I attempted to flag it instead.

Comment: @Pipsqweek you can accept an answer if any worked for you.If none , then you can post ur own solution which worked for you and accept it.